Sending SOL in Python with Solders from a JSON file
So I've been struggling with writing a function to transfer all SOL from different wallets in a json file to a single destination wallet.
Note: The wallets in wallets.json are formatted as below:
{"index": 4,
"type": "buy wallet",
"public key": "7CFFMZ6MDtvBGh996vJEuKiYrgeNBKzgpp2fjHNaZfZ5",
"private key": "5ioxaWvhwBgbvXEMKs12p8tt8w44yxgsgGVAmi75HXihrh1MeuiusTavsxkD7W4eQEuScoCFQXRfhFKVvz8v8L3d"}

My Code:
from solders.keypair import Keypair # type: ignore
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.system_program import transfer, TransferParams
from solders.transaction import VersionedTransaction # type: ignore
from solders.message import MessageV0 # type: ignore
import json


SOLANA_RPC_URL = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
client = Client(SOLANA_RPC_URL)

with open(r"C:\Users\Fabsen\Desktop\Coding\Python\Projekte\Volume Bot\wallets.json", "r") as file:
    wallets_data = json.load(file)
    
def create_keypair(public_key: str, private_key: str) -> Keypair:
    private_bytes = bytes.fromhex(private_key)
    return Keypair.from_secret_key(private_bytes)

senders = [
    create_keypair(wallet['public key'], wallet['private key'])
    for wallet in wallets_data
]

receiver = input(str("To which Address should be the SOL sent? \n --> "))

blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash()

transactions = []
for sender in senders:
    ix = transfer(
        TransferParams(
            from_pubkey=sender.pubkey,
            to_pubkey=receiver.pubkey,
            lamports=2140000,
        )
    )
    
msg = MessageV0.try_compile(
    payer=sender.pubkey(),
    instructions=[ix],
    address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
    recent_blockhash=blockhash,
)

tx = VersionedTransaction(msg, [sender])
transactions.append(tx)

for i, tx in enumerate(transactions):
    print(f"Transaction {i + 1}: {tx}")

I've tried some code before, but the program always crashed when I put in the destination wallet. I've rewritten everything then and when I now try to run the script following error pops up:
Exception has occurred: ValueError
non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
 private_bytes = bytes.fromhex(private_key)


Your public key and private key are stored as base-58 strings in wallets.json, so you'll need to interpret them differently. You can use a package like base58 https://pypi.org/project/base58/ to do that, ie:
import base58
import json

with open(r"C:\Users\Fabsen\Desktop\Coding\Python\Projekte\Volume Bot\wallets.json", "r") as file:
    wallets_data = json.load(file)
    
def create_keypair(public_key: str, private_key: str) -> Keypair:
    private_bytes = base58.b58decode(private_key)
    return Keypair.from_secret_key(private_bytes)

